# Angular: How can I stop my $http calls from blocking the UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

In my controller I have the following code:

```
PartnersService.GetNonPartnerBanks().success(function (data) {
        vm.nonPartnerBanksList = data;
    }).error( function () {
        vm.nonPartnerBanksList = [];
    });
```

Which calls this service:

```
service.GetNonPartnerBanks = function() {
            var nonPartnerBankUrl = config.baseUrl + 'public/nonPartnerBanks';
            return $http.get(nonPartnerBankUrl);
        };
```

This all works but if the server takes longer to reply, the application's UI freezes up.

What am I doing wrong doesn't the `$http` service use AJAX and promises so that the rendering of the UI should continue while the call is being made ?

The part of the template which uses the data:

```
<ol class="nya-bs-select nya-dashboard"
    required

    name="futurePartner"
    id="futurePartner"
    ng-model="npc.futurePartner"
    data-size="5"
    ng-change="npc.hideSucessMessage()"
    title-tpl="<span>{{npc.partnerSelectTitle}}</span>"
    deep-watch="true"
    no-search-title-tpl="<span>{{'general.NoSearchResult' | translate}}</span>"
    data-live-search="true">
    <li nya-bs-option="bankItem in npc.futurePartnerList" data-value="bankItem.id">
        <a>
            {{bankItem.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Follow up:

Vita's answer put me on the right trail, it wasn't that $http blocked my UI, I had an animation on ajax calls which gave the impression of the Ui freezing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http calls are asynchronnous, it returns promise, you can use .then and .catch as ussual on it (success and error callbacks are there just for historical reasons and they are deprecated)

But even them are not blocking your UI, it has to be something different.

What does the "freeze" means?

From where is the method called? 
Do you use it in route obejct resolve attribute? If yes - then its the feature of it - its waiting for all promises to be fullfiled.

Definitelly problem is somewhere else.
Can you provide more information? Or even better some jsbin?

Comment: Freeze in my case means the screen is completely white, I'm using data to populate some dropdowns (nya-bs-select), I'm not using route resolve.

Comment: I've added the portion of the view which the vm is feeding, the dropdown list, but I can't post a bigger example as it's part of a huge controller/view (which I can't break up)

Comment: Hmm, i don't know the internals of this directive ... but, how many of the items are in the array? How large is the item itself( is there name and id or much more? and what exactly "deep-watch" does (its not in nya-bs-select documentation, so I suppose its yours). I am thinking about just slowness of rendering. Do you have ng-stats on projects, it can tell you, how many watchers and how long is the digest cycle, so if there isnt some watch which takes too much time. I really cant see anything strange at the first sight, but I would say that your controllers shouldn't be huge :/

Comment: The elements in the array are simple objects with a name field and id, I will try to install ng-stats as to see what's going on, deep-watch isn't my attribute it's oficial but unlisted (removing it I've tried and it doesn't help)